# dhcpcd.service does not exist

Tags: arch-linux, dhcpcd

I have a new Arch Linux installation but trouble getting network. When I boot up interface eth0 is DOWN by default so run `ip link set eth0 up`. The problem is when I trying to run `systemctl enable dhcpcd` it says dhcpcd.service does not exist (also tried dhclient). Not sure where to go from there

[image]

Comment: Probably because you didn't specify either of them when you pacstrap. Either use systemd-networkd (and -resolved), or boot back the installation medium and mount and arch-chroot and pacman to install them.

Comment: Does `systemctl status systemd-networkd` is running?

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't have `dhcpcd` isntalled.Try `pacman -S dhcpcd`. This will install `dhcpcd` and the service